# Samba set share browsable only for a group

Tags: files, samba

How I can configure samba to set browsable a share for a group only.

I want to hide the share for all other users, if a set browsable to `yes` all the users can see the share when explore. I don't want this behavior.

Example a simple share

```
[myshare]
    force group = mygroup
    write list = mygroup
    read list = mygroup
    browsable = yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add

```
hide unreadable = yes
hide unwriteable files = yes
```

Comment: This is a per file basis.

Comment: does not work, I have to put in global configuration